# Java, how do you have a user enter their values in one line with no spaces?

Tags: java

I'm new to learning java. My current assignment is to have the user enter the values they want with an operator and come out with a result on one line with no spaces.
I figured out most of the code, but I'm having trouble running it without adding the spaces.
For example:
1 + 1 = 2 (This will work)
1+1 (this causes an error)

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mod2 {
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int value1;
    static int value2;
    static int result;
    String input = "";

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Mod2 m = new Mod2();
        
        System.out.println("Beginning Application");
        System.out.println("Enter expression like [value][operator][value2] no spaces");
        
        value1 = m.sc.nextInt();
        String input = m.sc.next();
        value2 = m.sc.nextInt();
        
        switch (input) {
        case "+":   
            result = (value1 + value2);
            System.out.println(result);
            break;
        case "-":   
            result = (value1 - value2);
            System.out.println(result);
            break;
        case "*":   
            result = (value1 * value2);
            System.out.println(result);
            break;
        case "/":   
            result = (value1 / value2);
            System.out.println(result);
            break;
        case "%":   
            result = (value1 % value2);
            System.out.println(result);
            break;
        }
            
        System.out.println("Ending application");               
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the input string by the operator then use the first half of that string as value 1 then second half as value 2.

`input.split("-");` // you can use a regex expression here to check for the existence of the operator

```
 ...
    String input = m.sc.next();
    String[] operation = input.split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
    Integer value1 = Integer.parseInt(operation[0]);
    Integer value2 = Integer.parseInt(operation[2]);

    switch (operation[1]) {
      case "+":
        result = (value1 + value2);
        break;
      case "-":
        result = (value1 - value2);
        break;
      case "*":
        result = (value1 * value2);
        break;
      case "/":
        result = (value1 / value2);
        break;
      case "%":
        result = (value1 % value2);
        break;
    }
    
    System.out.println(result);
```

That should let you input "2+2" and produce 4 as result

Comment: Hello Nia, I liked that you cleaned up my code a little. It looks way more efficient. Your method works great too! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For the `nextXXX()`-methods (except nextLine()) [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) uses strings up to some delimiter as its tokens. By default, whitespace is used as delimiter. Since e. g. string "100+50" doesn't contain any whitespace, it's a single token. This token is not an int, therefore a call on `nextInt()` will fail.

What can you do? Either you read the whole line using `nextLine()`, then you'll have to parse it on your own.

Or, you use different delimiters. E.g.

```
m.sc.useDelimiter("[^0-9]"); // delimiter is any non-digit.
int value1 = m.sc.nextInt(); 
m.sc.useDelimiter("[0-9]");  // delimiter is any digit
String operator = m.sc.next();
m.sc.useDelimiter("[^0-9]"); // delimiter is any non-digit.
int value2 = m.sc.nextInt();
```

The delimiter is a regular expression. You can find more information on those in the documentation for [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

EDIT: note, the used expressions won't work with negative numbers.

Comment: Hello Mihe, I had to make one little change from String operator to String input. But other than that, it worked! I haven't been introduced to Delimiter just yet. But I'll take a look into it. Thank you!

Comment: As this is homework, I do not post full working solutions :-) Another hint: you'll need a delimiter that uses a lookbehind expression (like the one in Nia's answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand but the problem occurs when there is space in the right operator?

You can simply remove the operator spaces before entering the switch, like this:

```
input = input.replaceAll(" ","");

switch (input) {...
```